# Open-source EDA project

Tags: open-source

Do you know any open-source project in EDA (Electronic Design Automation) looking for C++ programmers?

Comment: related: [Looking to write electrical engineering related open software](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581533/looking-to-write-electrical-engineering-related-open-software)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to talk to the owners of Icarus Verilog or Verilator. There are a host of other tools on freshmeat too which are into EDA and open source.

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to get into gEDA if you hang out on their mailing list. Details: http://www.gpleda.org/developer.html

Answer (score 4):

I dig up this old topic, but we from the KiCad EDA project still searching for new developers and testers. KiCad is a GPL'ed suite for drawing schematics, printed circuit boards and viewing gerbers. Its written in C++ with the wxWidgets toolkit and is able to work native on Windows, Linux/BSD and Mac OSX.

Read more about the project at:
http://www.kicad-eda.org

And the project is now hosted at launchpad.

Answer (score 3):

We extensively used [Electric](http://www.staticfreesoft.com/) during our VLSI and Microelectronics classes. The project is sponsored by Sun and may soon get orphaned in the post Oracle days. It will be worthwhile contacting them and offering assistance. It is a great tool worth supporting.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any that are actively looking for C++ software developers.

However, if you implement or improve a feature, or fix a bug, you can make a pull request from their open-source repository. E.g., take a conference paper from DAC/ICCAD, implement it and integrate it into the open-source repository.

Some examples below are stuff to experiment with and learn from.

Xyce (best open-source circuit simulator): https://xyce.sandia.gov/index.html

The EPFL Logic Synthesis Libraries: https://github.com/lsils/lstools-showcase

EDA projects that are part of the OpenROAD program/initiative: https://theopenroadproject.org/

If you check out research papers from DAC, ICCAD, and DATE (the top research conferences in EDA), you can find some software developments releasing their work as open source on Github or elsewhere.